# How I can find the contents of inner nesting?

Tags: groovy

Lets say I have a string like this :

```
string = [+++[>>[--]]]abced
```

Now I want a someway to return a list that has: `[[--],[>>],[+++]]`. That is the contents of the deepest `[` nesting followed by other nesting. I came up with this solution like this :

```
def string = "[+++[>>[--]]]"
loop = []
temp = []
string.each {
    bool = false
    if(it == "["){
        temp = []
        bool = true
    }
    else if( it != "]")
        temp << it 
    if(bool)
         loop << temp

}
println loop.reverse()
```

But this indeed takes the `abced` string after the last `]` and put into the result!. But what I want is only `[[--],[>>],[+++]]`

Are there any groovy way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, if you wouldn't mind using recursion

```
def sub(s , list){
    if(!s.contains('[') && !s.contains('[')) 
        return list
    def clipped = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('[')+1, s.indexOf(']'))
    list.add(clipped)
    s = s - "[$clipped]"
    sub(s , list)
}
```

Calling

```
sub('''[+++[>>[--]]]abced''' , [])
```

returns a list of all subportions enclosed between braces.

```
['--', '>>', '+++']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your brackets are symmetrical, you could just introduce a counter variable that holds the depth of the bracket nesting. Only depth levels above 0 are allowed in the output:

```
def string = "[+++[>>[--]]]abc"
loop = []
temp = []
depth = 0;
string.each {
  bool = false
  if(it == "["){
    temp = []
    bool = true
    depth++;
  }   
  else if (it == "]"){
    depth--;
  }   
  else if (depth > 0){ 
    temp << it  
  }   
  if(bool){
    loop << temp
  }   
}
println loop.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {

    private static final def pattern = ~/([^\[]*)\[(.+?)\][^\]]*/

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def string = "[+++[>>[--]]]abced"

        def result = match(string)
        println result

    }

    static def match(String val) {
        def matcher = pattern.matcher(val);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(1) ? match(matcher.group(2)) + matcher.group(1) : match(matcher.group(2))
        }
        [val]
    }
}
```

`System.out`

```
[--, >>, +++]
```

The capturing of the first group in the regex pattern could probably be improved. Right now the first group is any character that is not `[` and if there are nothing in front of the first `[` then the first group will contain an empty string.